# RxSwift - optional issue on binding to tableView

Tags: ios, swift, generics, option-type, rx-swift

I have an `UITableView` and a `users` variable whose signature is like:

```
let users: Variable<[User]?> = Variable<[User]?>(nil)
```

While I'm trying to bind this array of users in a UITableView, I'm getting the error `Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred`. This only occurs when I'm observing an Optional type. Why does this happen? What's the workaround for this situation?

Here is an example of how I'm doing:

```
private func bind() {
    // Does not compile: Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred
    users.asObservable().bind(to:
        tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "UserCell",
            cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (index, user, cell) in
            // Cell setup.
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `filterNil()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see this error because the compiler cannot infer the type of the `Optional` variable `users` passed into the following functions which work on generics and need to be able to infer the type.

An `Optional` in Swift is actually implemented as shown below. I guess in case of an `Optional` being potentially `nil` aka `.none` the compiler cannot infer the type for methods like e.g. `items` and `bind(to:)` which work on generics.

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

    /// The absence of a value.
    ///
    /// In code, the absence of a value is typically written using the `nil`
    /// literal rather than the explicit `.none` enumeration case.
    case none

    /// The presence of a value, stored as `Wrapped`.
    case some(Wrapped)

    /// Creates an instance that stores the given value.
    public init(_ some: Wrapped)
    //...
}
```

**Workaround 1.)**: You could just use `filterNil()` (`RxOptionals` lib) to avoid the problem.

```
private func bind() {
    users.asObservable().filterNil().bind(to:
        tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "UserCell",
            cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (index, user, cell) in
            // Cell setup.
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

**Workaround 2.)**: Make `users` non-optional. If you have no users just set an empty array as value.

```
let users: Variable<[User]> = Variable<[User]>([])
```

**Workaround 3.)**: Use [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) `??` in `map` function like

```
private func bind() {
    users.asObservable().map { optionalUsers -> [User] in 
          return optionalUsers ?? [] 
        }
        .bind(to:
        tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "UserCell",
            cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (index, user, cell) in
            // Cell setup.
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

**Sidenote**: `Variable` is deprecated in the latest version of RxSwift

*Just for reference:*

Implementation of `items`

```
public func items<S: Sequence, Cell: UITableViewCell, O : ObservableType>
    (cellIdentifier: String, cellType: Cell.Type = Cell.self)
    -> (_ source: O)
    -> (_ configureCell: @escaping (Int, S.Iterator.Element, Cell) -> Void)
    -> Disposable
    where O.E == S {
    return { source in
        return { configureCell in
            let dataSource = RxTableViewReactiveArrayDataSourceSequenceWrapper<S> { (tv, i, item) in
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
                let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
                configureCell(i, item, cell)
                return cell
            }
            return self.items(dataSource: dataSource)(source)
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of `bind(to:)`

```
public func bind<O: ObserverType>(to observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
    return self.subscribe(observer)
}
```

Comment: The most applicable workaround would be the first one, since my user object is a `Mappable` (ObjectMapper) and has no initializer without parameters. Had no idea about `filterNil` function. It's important to tell that it's from the `RxOptionals` lib.

Comment: @juniorgarcia I updated my answer with your suggestion and also offered a third workaround

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error without an optional type. It happened because I was using a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass in a `UITableView`.